# Is there a way to setEditors for a certain range using Google Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set Editors for a certain range on the sheet. I found this function called getEditors() that gives a list of all the editors for a certain defined range. Can we set editors too?

Answer (score 0):

### The class [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeEditor(String)) features different methods that allow you to modify the editors of a [spreadsheet range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

> To set an editor you can use the method [addEditor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#addeditoremailaddress), to delete
>   editors, use [removeEditor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditoremailaddress).

[Sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect):

```
// Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');

// Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
// permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
```